# Type could be instantiated with a different subtype - how to check what subtype I have?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So I am processing the result of a fetch call like this:

```js
const response = await fetch(url, config);
const contentType = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
let responseBody: T;
if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
  responseBody = await response.json();
} else {
  responseBody = await response.text();
}
```

Also note that `<T extends ResponseBody>` and `ResponseBody` is a union of many interfaces I expect to get from the API and `string`

So logically, if the API returns a json, I want to parse it as a json and if it returns a text, I want to parse it as a text, all are allowed for type T.

But I keep getting an error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ResponseBody'.

So what can I do in this case? How can I make sure what subtype was `responseBody` instantiated with? I am confused what to do in this situation I'm very new to TypeScript and static typing in general, thanks.

Comment: Why is `responseBody` of type `T` rather than simply being of type `ResponseBody`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `T` is generic, anything that is *more specific* than your requirements can be used.

For example, if your generic was `T extends {foo: number}`, you could pass `{foo: number, bar: string}` to it. Any value for this type can be passed to the constraint.

Notice that the opposite is not valid. If you make a `{foo: 1}`, you would not be able to assign that to a `T` because the `T` also requires `bar: string`.

Similarly, your `T extends string | SomethingElse` could receive just `SomethingElse`, meaning that `T` does not accept a string.